# Масштабирование картинки в блоке рядом с сайдбаром

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно разместить картинку в блоке, который расположен справа от сайдбара.
Если я задаю стиль самой картинке, то она увеличивается до размеров, заданных блоку.
Если задаю стиль блоку, то граница блока разлетается за сайдбар.

```css
.sidebar {
    background: white;
    height: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    padding: 40px 46px 46px 46px;

   }

.sidebar-button{
 display: block;
 height: 28px;
 width: 240px;
 border-top: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
 border-right: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
 border-left: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
 padding-left: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: gray;
 padding-top: 12px;

}

.auto
{
 border-bottom: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
}

.sidebar-button:hover{
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 color: black;
 padding-left: 40px;
 width: 220px;
}

.bike-picture {
 border: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
 margin: 40px 46px 46px 26px;
 width: auto;
 height: 400px;
 padding-top: 40px; 
 text-align: center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Ноутбуки</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Планшеты</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Телефоны</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Телевизоры</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Бытовая техника</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button auto" href="#">Автотовары</a>  
</div>

<div>
 <img class="bike-picture" src="img/bike.png" alt="Bike">
</div>
```

```
введите сюда код
```

[image: What I need]

Answer (score 1):

попробуй так

```css
.sidebar {
    background: white;
    height: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    padding: 40px 46px 46px 46px;

   }

.sidebar-button{
 display: block;
 height: 28px;
 width: 240px;
 border-top: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
 border-right: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
 border-left: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
 padding-left: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: gray;
 padding-top: 12px;

}

.auto
{
 border-bottom: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
}

.sidebar-button:hover{
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 color: black;
 padding-left: 40px;
 width: 220px;
}

.kartka { /*родитель*/
  width: 200px; /*ширина родительского блока*/
  border: #c8c8c8 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 46px 46px 26px;
  float: left;
  }

.kartka img {
  width: 90%; /* задаете шырину относительно родителя  */
  padding: 10px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Ноутбуки</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Планшеты</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Телефоны</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Телевизоры</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button" href="#">Бытовая техника</a>  
 <a class="sidebar-button auto" href="#">Автотовары</a>  
</div>

<div class="kartka">
 <img  src="http://www.bikehiredirect.com/images/pix/MaleBike1.jpg" alt="Bike">
  <p>Описание велика</p>
</div>
```